# The exports statement in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in *server.js*

```
var http = require('http');

function start() {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        console.log('onrequest called');
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' });
        response.write("Hello world!");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server started!");
}

exports.start = start;
```

And the following in *index.js*

```
var server = require('./server');
server.start();
```

What I'm not understanding is how the line `exports.start = start;` is working. Where is `exports` coming from? Why does index.js invoke the start method by `server.start();` rather than `exports.start()`? Isn't `exports` just a variable we put in the global namespace to make make a local var accessible to other modules by sticking it as a property on the global variable `exports`?

Help!

Comment: `exports` is refers to the same object as `module.exports`. It just exports the function `start` on property `start` and then you can invoke it in a different module.

Comment: @AndrewLi,  You're right.  https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_exports

Comment: `exports` is not a statement, it's just a regular JS object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node wraps each module in it's own `IIFE` that provides arguments such as `module`, `exports`, `__dirname`, etc.

So when you write:

```
var http = require('http');

function start() {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        console.log('onrequest called');
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' });
        response.write("Hello world!");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server started!");
}

exports.start = start;
```

It's actually being wrapped in something like:

```
(function(module, exports, __dirname, ...) {
  var http = require('http');

  function start() {
      function onRequest(request, response) {
          console.log('onrequest called');
          response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' });
          response.write("Hello world!");
          response.end();
      }

      http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
      console.log("Server started!");
  }

  exports.start = start;
})(module, exports, __dirname, ...)
```

> What I'm not understanding is how the line exports.start = start; is
>   working. Where is exports coming from?

`exports` is an object just like any other JS object. You are attaching a reference to `start` on `exports.start`.

> Why does index.js invoke the start method by server.start(); rather than exports.start()?

Good question. Since `exports` is just an object, `exports.start` won't reference anything unless you provide that reference by requiring a module.

You can, however, do this if your objective is to not have a local variable.

`require('./server').start()`

Comment: __dirname is not exposed in globals.

Comment: @Vikramaditya, `__dirname` is global to the module and is provided in the `IIFE` . https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer @raphael-rafatpanah 

In the second part of my original question what I meant was...why don't we have simply `require('./server'); exports.start();` in _index.js_? I am assuming NodeJS starts off with an array `exports` of exported properties, then sequentially passes that `exports` to each module IIFE as it encounters them. These modules, having received `exports` as a param into their IIFE are appending properties to that `exports` variable. So by the time index.js's `exports.start();` is reached, it should know that's the `start()` in server.js, right?

Comment: No.  You can try this yourself to see.  If `exports` was global, then you can imagine that you would `require('./server')` in one module, and access `exports.start()` in another one.  Further, if two modules both exported `start`, and you required both files, how would that work?  Thankfully, when you `require` a module, you get whatever was `export`ed as a local variable to the `module`, and no where else.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: So each the `module`, `exports` etc are _local_ to each module. So the `require(..)` function must be returning a reference to the module imported. So, in _index.js_, this would work: `require('./server'); module.children[0].exports.start();` Of course this isn't elegant but it clears up what's coming from where, which is what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear, it appears, require(...) returns an object literal with all the exported properties of the requested module.

Comment: `module.children[0].exports.start();` may work or it may not.  It depends if `children[0]` points to the correct server module.  You can experiment to see how this works with multiple modules, and by changing the order of `require`s.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is just in the context of a very simple "hello world" :)